# how to build an EXTJS4 mvc demo with desktop module

Tags: extjs, extjs-mvc

My code can load the Model, View, Controller, but the launch function does not work.

I want every icon on the desktop to be a App so it can load the Model, View, Controller when each has been clicked. How to do this?

```
Ext.define('MyApp.GridWindow', {
    extend: 'Ext.ux.desktop.Module',

    requires: [
        'Ext.data.ArrayStore',
        'Ext.util.Format',
        'Ext.grid.Panel',
        'Ext.grid.RowNumberer'
    ],

    id:'grid-win',

    init : function(){
        this.launcher = {
            text: 'Grid Window',
            iconCls:'icon-grid',
            handler : this.createWindow,
            scope: this
        };
    },

    createWindow : function(){
        var desktop = this.app.getDesktop();
        var win = desktop.getWindow('grid-win');

        if(!win){

          Ext.application({
              name: 'USER',
              appFolder: PUB+'/extjs4/mUser',
              controllers: [
                  "User"
              ],
              launch: function () {
                  win = desktop.createWindow({
                      id: 'notepad',
                      title:'Notepad',
                      width:600,
                      height:400,
                      iconCls: 'notepad',
                      animCollapse:false,
                      border: false,
                      hideMode: 'offsets',
                      layout: 'fit',
                      items: [{
                          xtype: 'htmleditor',
                          //xtype: 'textarea',
                          id: 'notepad-editor'
                       }]
                   });
               }
        });

        win.show();
        return win;
},
```

Answer (score 0):

try (1)onLaunch Function in your Controller section or launch function at the very end of your app.js like (2)

(1)

```
onLaunch:function()
        {}
```

(2)

```
launch:function(){
//runs when controllers init function is completed
}
```